# Istio side car external storage mounting issue

Tags: azure, istio, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I am using istio sidecar auto injection , I have grpc transcrpter Envoy Fliter which need a file which is mounted on shared drive on azure.But side car is not able to mount that directory because I have mounting configuration in my pod.

> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 kind: EnvoyFilter metadata:
>   name: {{ .Values.filter.name }} namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
>
> spec: workloadLabels: app: {{ .Values.grpc.appname}} filters:
>
> listenerMatch: portNumber: 50051 listenerType: SIDECAR_INBOUND
>   listenerProtocol: HTTP insertPosition: index: FIRST relativeTo:
>   envoy.router filterName: envoy.grpc_json_transcoder filterType: HTTP
>   filterConfig: protoDescriptor: {{ .Values.storage.mount }}/{{
>   .Values.filter.file }} services: com.demo.DemoService printOptions:
>   alwaysPrintPrimitiveFields: True

in my pod file I have

> volumeMounts:
>   - mountPath: {{ .Values.storage.mount}} name: {{ .Values.storage.volume}}

and

> volumes:
>   - name: {{ .Values.storage.volume}} azureFile: secretName: {{ .Values.storage.secret}} shareName: {{ .Values.storage.shareName}}
>   readOnly: true

Envoy filter is complains to pick this file because it didn't found path.

To solve this problem I have disabled Auto istio side car injection and used below instruction to add mount.
https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/

Answer (score 2):

I think in your specific case, you can still rely on automatic istio-sidecar-injector, and make use of `sidecar.istio.io/userVolume` annotation of Pod to which injection is made. As its name implies, it lets you to configure user defined volumes in sidecar-injector template in JSON format.

You can find an example of its usage [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/7a5a548462939d6b513b73d5060f738c7f6e89c7/pilot/pkg/kube/inject/testdata/inject/deployment-user-volume.yaml).